# Is len() thread safe in golang?

Tags: go

I'm logging every second the length of a map; I don't care if I have the "exact" value / race conditions (off by one is ok). I'm interested to know if this could cause a panic and if I **have** to enclose `len()` with some `.RLock()/Unlock()` or not.

I'm asking because **concurrent reads/writes in a map will cause a panic** (Go detects that) but I don't know if reading the length counts as a "read". I have tried with a test program but cannot produce a crash but I'd rather have an exact answer, at least for the sake of it.

If it matters I'm interested in both len for arrays and for maps.
Thanks!

Comment: len on an array is a compile time constant and is therefore thread-safe.  If you meant to ask about len on a slice, then the answer is no.

Comment: yes sorry I meant slice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a race condition. The results are undefined. For example,

`racer.go`:

```
package main

func main() {
    m := make(map[int]int)
    l := 0
    go func() {
        for {
            l = len(m)
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        m[i] = i
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c00008e000 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:8 +0x5f

Previous write at 0x00c00008e000 by main goroutine:
  runtime.mapassign_fast64()
      /home/peter/go/src/runtime/map_fast64.go:92 +0x0
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:12 +0xba

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:6 +0x92
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

---

References:

[Wikipedia: Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

[The Go Blog: Introducing the Go Race Detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

[Go: Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

[Benign Data Races: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180923140315/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong)

Comment: So it is a race for the exactness of the answer but if I'm just interested in "acceptable values"  and no panics (such as read/write in a map) is it ok?

Comment: @Thomas: The results of a data race are undefined. Don't do it! See my reference for the perils of "benign" data races.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept dirty data of `len()`, the operation will not cause deadlock, and will not cause any panic.

I met this problem in this scenario: I will decide if I need to clean the expired data in a map by if length of map reach the limitation. But I need not exactly limit the size of the map, because write operation is enclosed by `.Lock()/Unlock()` and will also check the limitation.

Hope this scenario will help you. However if `len()` is not a high frequency called, I think enclose that with lock is better.